# Deny access to a folder when accessed from certain url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the site `example.com`.

In one of its folders, I have a different site which is accessed through the domain `exampleSubSite.com` and the folder of the second site is called `/exampleSubSiteFolder/`.

The access is made via redirect in the `.htaccess` of the main site:

```
 RewriteRule ^exampleSubSiteFolder - [L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exampleSubSite\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ exampleSubSiteFolder/$1 [L]
```

However, I **DO NOT** want this folder to be accessible from the URL of the main site:

`exampleSite.com/exampleSubSiteFolder/`

Can someone, please help me with that? I know the solution is bad as a whole, but this does not depend on me.

Comment: is this 2.2 or 2.4? Are you the admin of the site?

Comment: Yes, I am Apache version is 2.4.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it In virtualhost context (only works on 2.4.x):

```
<Directory /path/to/exampleSubSiteFolder>
    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'exampleSite.com'">
        Require all denied
    </If>
    <Else>
        Require all granted
    </Else>
</Directory>
```

If you were not the admin and only have access to .htaccess, I would just place inside a .htaccess in the specified directory:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'exampleSite.com'">
    Require all denied
</If>
<Else>
    Require all granted
</Else>
```

My recommendation, never use .htaccess if you can admin the site and main conf, virtualhosts,etc.

This is all assuming you have only a single "catch-all" virtualhost of course and/or .htaccess.

If you have a virtualhost for each name (which is what everyone should do), it will be enough with having Require all denied or granted where appropiate in each virtualhost.

Comment: Wow, that was great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To do this, inside the folder named `exampleSubSiteFolder` create a `.htaccess` file and add the following inside of it:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

However, if you're using Apache 2.4, then you would use the following instead:

```
Require all denied
```

So anyone that tries to access `exampleSubSite.com/exampleSubSiteFolder/` would be stopped.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I did not explain correct /exampleSubSiteFolder/ is the root folder of the site exampleSubSite.com so I am worried if this change would make the folder inaccessible at any ways or only f accessed as exampleSite.com/exampleSubSiteFolder/